# Profile for lein's "install" and "jar" tasks

Tags: clojure, leiningen

In my project.clj, I'm trying to set up some jvm-opts for when I do `lein run`, `lein jar`, `lein uberjar`, and `lein install`.

So far, only the `uberjar` and `dev` entries seem to work (I can read them via `System/getProperty` at runtime)

```
:profiles {:dev     {:jvm-opts ["-Dcompiling-utils=true"]}
           :uberjar {:jvm-opts ["-Dcompiling-utils=true"]}
           :install {:jvm-opts ["-Dcompiling-utils=true"]}}
```

How do I get a profile for `lein install` and `lein jar` ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a given task you can activate a profile by using the higher-order task [with-profile](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md#activating-profiles):

```
lein with-profile install install
lein with-profile install jar
```